# Shopify cart/update abandoned carts

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Does Shopify carts/update Webhooks fire when the cart session expires?

I need to interact with the cart each time it is updated - I also need to do something when the cart expires. Shopify keeps a cart alive for 14 days before clearing it...

I can't wait 14 days to test if it fires a Webhook...

Some people will suggest I hook into abandoned checkouts - but I need access to the cart.

*****Edit***** - I know I can hook into the add/remove events with my own listener... But I need access to the cart when the customer isn't interacting with it - they've abandoned their cart... its been 14 days... their session has expired and all the items within their cart have been returned to inventory.

I need to trigger something when their cart expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cart/Update webhook has a both a token and timestamp. If no order arrives matching the token within 14 days, you can do what you need to do with the now expired cart.

Comment: They have a cart/update webhook which fires whenever something is added or removed from the cart https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/webhook I don't understand why, when they already do this, it would be silly overhead to send the webhook every 14 days when they delete the cart cookie... surely thats the same overhead? It would be a single event?

Comment: I see that! Right. So you have one extra step. Since you listen to cart/update, note the token and also listen to orders. If you don't get an order matching the cart token within 14 days of the last update, you know it's expired, you can thus deal with that moment as you need to.

Comment: Ahha! so the order contains a copy of the cart token? - thanks! this will make it simple to reconcile.